# android:allowbackup="false" not working

Tags: android, security, android-manifest

I am setting `android:allowbackup="false"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file but still i am able to take backup my complete app as apk with some app saver application. How is it possible?
I want to disable backup.

Comment: Not sure: some applications backup (with root i think) just copy everything of your App folder and then copy it when the user wants. And, if i'm not wrong the allowbackup attribute is used by the system to know if it should backup your application data when the user ask to execute the backup of the phone.

Comment: Is there any other way to avoid backup in Android Application.

Answer (score 1):

[android:allowbackup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) controls whether the application's data gets backed up.

It doesn't mediate access to the application's apk.

In my experience, the apk is stored as a world-readable file in `/data/app`.
Thus, some app saver application can easily copy it from there.

I heard that Jelly Bean and up supports "[forward locking](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/adb/commandline.c#L155)" the apk, but I haven't seen any technical details about it.

Comment: Thank you very much. need to apply some other way (encryption) to protect data